# Number of pages required for an index

Tags: database

I'm trying to work out how many pages would be required If I was to index carID on the following table.

### employeeID | name     |  carID

```
    1      | John     |  null
    2      | Jack     |   52
    3      | Rob      |   42
```

and so on...

If each page was able to hold, say, 100 record pointers and the table had 3000 rows. Then I know if there were no null values then there would be:
(3000/ 100) = 30 pages of leaf nodes. So 31 pages total to index carID.

However, I'm unsure what happens if there are null values. Surely you don't need to index them? If there were only 1000 cars in the car table lets say (so 2000 null values were present). Would the index of carID require (1000/100) = 10 pages?

Thanks

Comment: What RDDMS is this for? SQL Server 2008 will index NULLs by default but they can be excluded using filtered indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NULL` values do not get indexed.

As far as exactly how many pages are needed, it depends on the specific database you're using and probably database settings.

Comment: That depends. In Oracle or Postgres tuples where **all** index columns are NULL will not be indexed. If at least one of the index column is not null, the tuple will be part of the index, even if other columns are NULL.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, the question was about an index on `CarID`.  NULL values do not get indexed in most databases.  Of course there could be exceptions in some database, but Roger didn't specify which DBMS was talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes are represented using [B-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) structures rather than linear sorted lists so calculating the size of the index is probably not doable with with a simple formula.

Update: Please also note that it is not a rule that NULL values are not indexed. It is dependent on the database engine, as explained here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)#Effect_on_index_operation